# Browser identification (get_browser) for Firefox v.25

Tags: php

Are there any issues with the get_browser identification of Firefox v.25? This is a simple code:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "<br>";
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

it returns correct info for all browsers except Firefox. For Firefox I am getting the following output:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
Array (
    [browser_name_regex] => §^.*$§
    [browser_name_pattern] => *
    [comment] => Default Browser
    [browser] => Default Browser
    [version] => 0.0
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 0
    [platform] => unknown
    [platform_version] => unknown
    [alpha] => 
    [beta] => 
    [win16] => 
    [win32] => 
    [win64] => 
    [frames] => 
    [iframes] => 
    [tables] => 
    [cookies] => 
    [backgroundsounds] => 
    [javascript] => 
    [vbscript] => 
    [javaapplets] => 
    [activexcontrols] => 
    [ismobiledevice] => 
    [issyndicationreader] => 
    [crawler] => 
    [cssversion] => 0 
    [aolversion] => 0 
)
```

Am I missing something here? I have the latest browscap.ini from Jul 2013.

Thanks

UPDATE. I had to update the browscap.ini manually, because it missed the latest Firefox 25 definitions.

Comment: This looks like it's functioning exactly as intended. That being said, I still don't understand the issue.

Comment: Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0 - what's wrong with that?

Comment: All fields are empty. Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0 is not from "get_browser", but from $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. The get_browser command returns all empty fields

Comment: does `get_browser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], true)` give any different results?

Comment: It is just because the browscap.ini doesn't have the latest FF v.25. The latest browser definitions include only FF up to v.24.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was translated on Google translate

I am having the same problem, but I discovered that there is a new site to support the function `get_browser();`
To avoid the problem, go to the new site and download the latest version of the file browscap.ini
From here http://browscap.org/
And replace the old file with the new file
And restart the server
on the Linux operating system

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Or if you are using another system and software used to run a local server search for a tool that re-configuration of the server

It is a beautiful service has been activated on the new site are: 
You can test if the browser is present in the list of supported browsers by 
Bringing data browser, which by browsing the site via the static variable

```
$_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

For example, Firefox browser:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv: 25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
```

This data has been retrieved by the static variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`

And then be searched for in the file browser `browscap.ini`

To experience the service Go to new site and Click On: UA Lookup

## /* The Orginal Answer by Arabic */

كُنت اواجة نفس المُشكلة لكن اكتشفت ان هناك موقع جديد لدعم دالة `get_browser();` 
لتجنب المشكله اذهب الى الموقع الجديد وقم بتحميل اخر اصدار لملف `browscap.ini`
من هنا http://browscap.org/
واستبدل الملف القديم بالملف الجديد
و قم باعادة تشغيل الخادم
على نظام تشغيل Linux

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

او اذا كنت تستخدم نظام آخر وتستخدم برنامج لتشغيل خادم محلى قم بالبحث عن اداة اعادة التهيئة للخادم

ومن الخدمات الجميله التى تم تفعيلها على الموقع الجديد هى:
انك يمكنك اختبار إذا كان المتصفح موجود فى قائمة المتصفحات المدعومه عن طريق 
جلب بيانات المتصفح الذى تتصفح به الموقع عن طريق المتغير الثابت

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

فمثلاً متصفح فيرفوكس:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
```

تم جلب هذه البيانات عن طريق المتغير الثابت `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`

ويتم البحث بعد ذلك عن متصفحك فى ملف `browscap.ini`

لتجربة الخدمه اذهب الى الموقع الجديد واضغط على: UA Lookup